# Angular routing offical example usage of "+" syntax

Tags: angular

This is perhaps a silly question but I couldn't find an explanation anywhere else.

In the Angular official tutorial of routing, the following array is provided:

```
export const products = [
  {
    name: 'Phone XL',
    price: 799,
    description: 'A large phone with one of the best screens'
  },
  {
    name: 'Phone Mini',
    price: 699,
    description: 'A great phone with one of the best cameras'
  },
  {
    name: 'Phone Standard',
    price: 299,
    description: ''
  }
];
```

In the routing section, when displaying a single product details, the following syntax is used to get the current product index through the URL:

```
this.product = products[+params.get('protectId')];
```

I noticed that without the `'+'`, the params return null. Could anyone explain to me whats the purpose of the `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Angular Docs on [**`ParamMap`**](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#get)

> ### `get()`
>
> Retrieves a single value for a parameter.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> `string | null`: The parameter's single value, or the first value if the parameter has multiple values, or null when there is no such parameter.

That would mean that `params.get('protectId')` would return a `string`.

The `+` only converts the string into a number. That's all there is to it :)

Answer (score 0):

`params.get('protectId')` returns the ID as a string, the `+` typecasts it to an `int` (or `number`).

This is necessary since the array is indexed with numbers 0, 1, 2 and so on and not by '0', '1'.

Hence `products[+params.get('protectId')]` only works when you've typecasted it to an int.
To confirm, you can do it as: `products[Number(params.get('protectId'))]` and get the same result